# Java, Changing fonts and text colour.

Tags: java, android, fonts, colors

This is more of a general question, as I am still a beginning in the language of Java. I would like to know how can I make the font or text different? As well as its colour. An example for this is the MSN live messenger, for PC and Mac. In the chatbox, you can change the font and colour of the text, and it is also viewable by others, how can I make it like that for android?

Comment: You must have put some efforts before posting questions,

Comment: Here is a little reference:

[Fonts][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15500764/1147352

Answer (score 2):

In the **assets** folder of your project, create a new folder named **fonts**. Put **.ttf** files in there. [(You can download some here
)](http://www.1001freefonts.com/) These are files that contain fonts. Then, just to give you an idea of how to apply these fonts, here is an example of applying a font to a text view...

```
myTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/frquad.ttf"));
```

As for color, use this method...

```
myTextView.setTextColor();
```

Hopefully this has been of help.

Comment: is there a way we can somehow alter that into a button (drop down button)? for the user to choose? Or perhaps even a slider? To deter the colors.

Comment: @user3239104 Im sorry I dont really understand what your asking

Comment: So I want the users to be able to change their font and colour in a page, into any style they want. And I want the changing colour button to be a slider instead of a button, and when the user swipes the slider from one side to another, it will change a range of colours. And for picking fonts, they can tap on the drop down box and it shows a list of fonts, for the user to pick, and then their custom text will be showed in some kind of preview box.

Comment: @AggressiveDonut Thats quite a lot to answer in one question. You're going to have to split this question up into at least 4 or 5

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Font path
    String fontPath = "fonts/fontname.ttf";

    // text view label
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

    // Loading Font Face
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);

    // Applying font
    txt.setTypeface(tf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                context.getAssets(),
                "fonts/" +  "abcd.ttf");
        textView.setTypeface(typeFace);

Answer (score 0):

change the color:

```
radio2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bcbddc"));
```